# Removing file from browser cache

Tags: flash, caching

Is there any way to re-read the file from the server by site users? File was previously obtained with the large max-age. Changing the uri is technically impossible (/crossdomain.xml, directly requested by flash player).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want a flash application to obtain a new version of the file? Or do you want the users to obtain a new swf file?

Comment: I want to obtain a new version of the file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to obtain a new version of the file, you can call the filename with some query params. 
You can do something like this:

```
somedomain.com/filecached.xml?v=someRandomValue
```

If you add this parameter to the file url, a new version will be obtained.

Comment: Thanks, but: >> Changing the uri is technically impossible

Comment: Ok, so I don't understand what you need. What can you do? Either you go to every user browser and clean the cache, or you need to change something in the server for they to have a new file version. And technically, adding query parameters is not changing the uri.

Comment: Even with the additional variable, you are still requesting the same file from the server, cross domain should not care.

Comment: Server already has new file version, but previous cached on clients. I can't add any parameter, because file is requesting by flashplayer. Therefore needs another method (if it exists at all) to force requesting new version from server.

Comment: If the flash application is requesting the file, you can change the url in the flash application (adding a query parameter). This way flash application will request the new version of the file. To force your users to get the new flash application you can do the same in the html file where the swf is loaded. (e.g. src="app.swf?v=randomValue")